# sessions in php set and retrieve

Tags: php, session

In sample.php file i am setting and printing the values

```
session_start();  
$_SESSION['userid'] = "4";  
echo session_id();  
echo ' ' . $_SESSION['userid'] . ' ';  
print_r($_SESSION);
```

The output is

```
tv0p126mg6q8ksvhbueq029567 4 Array ( [userid] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 4 ) )
```

In second.php file i am trying to access userid session but its not set

```
session_start();  
echo session_id();  
echo ' ' . $_SESSION['userid'] . ' ';  
print_r($_SESSION);
```

Here my output is

```
tv0p126mg6q8ksvhbueq029567  Array ( )
```

Help me out in getting the session value in second.php file

Comment: Are you using the php default session handler?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your sessions are not being saved on the server. Check php.ini settings concerning sessions, and double-check that the location session files are being created in exists and is writable - it happened to me that I had a typo in the path and sessions weren't working as a result... had me stuck for hours!

Comment: It helps to log PHP errors and monitor the logfile to locate these type of problems.

Comment: If you cannot find and/or write session data, you could try configuring session saving with http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php

Comment: went to session store path /var/lib/php5 and session files are there. `sess_tv0p126mg6q8ksvhbueq029567`

Comment: Okay, and if you open the session file, do you see your data in serialized form?

Comment: when i open the session file i see no data inside.

Comment: Okay, well I have to ask... you set it to `"4"`, so why in the world is it coming out as an XMLElement?

Answer (score 0):

Maby not enough space on the server to store session data (if it's linux var directory by default ..i think). Check your server log, there should  found your answer ;)

Your code should work by the way.